# Custom font in Firebase Cloud function for creating a PDF

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-pdfkit

I am trying to use PDFKit in Firebase cloud functions to create a pdf with 1 line of text a custom font. I have created the folder 'fonts' and added the ttf to it. Only I constantly get this error in the logs:

> TestPdf Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'upc-a.tff' at
> Object.openSync (fs.js: 462: 3) at Object.readFileSync (fs.js: 364:
> 35) at

The function in question looks like this:

```
function generateBarcode (doc) {
   doc
   .font ('fonts / upc-a.tff')
     .fontSize (50)
     .text (
       "Testtest2",
       80,
       780,
       {align: "center", width: 500}
     );
}
```

I've already tried everything. I added the file in the root folder and tried the following options:

- .font ('fonts / upc-a.tff')
- .font ('./ fonts / upc-a.tff')
- .font ('/ fonts / upc-a.tff')
- .font ('upc-a.tff') (when the file was in the root folder)

This is a screenshot of the folders:
[image]

But all to no success. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Did you add the `fonts` folder under the `functions` folder? Normally, `.font('./fonts/upc-a.tff')` should work when you do that.

Comment: What do you mean by normal? I created a folder called fonts, and placed the ttf file in there. Is there another way?

Comment: Where exactly did you create the folder `fonts`? What is its parent? Can you show a screenshot of your project folders?

Comment: In the functions folder is the createInvoice.js file, which contains the relevant function (I updated the question). As you can see, the folder ./fonts/upc-a.tff is available there.

Comment: AFAIK it should work. The only thing that catch my eye is the fact you named the top folder "frontend", but I guess this is a Firebase Project.

Comment: Yes, that was my thoughts too, but thank you for your help so far! unfortunately I keep getting the same error. It is a test environment but indeed it is a firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be happening because you have created the file `upc-a.ttf` correctly but when you are providing the path in the function `generateBarcode` you are giving the path `./fonts/upc-a.tff` - a path with the wrong file extension.  It should be `.ttf` (TrueType font file extension), hence your file not found error.

Please change `.tff` to `.ttf` as below which would resolve your issue.

```js
function generateBarcode (doc) {
    doc
       .font('fonts/upc-a.ttf')
       .fontSize (50)
       .text(
           "Testtest2",80,780,{align: "center", width: 500}
       );
}
```